# Extracting Email Domain in Swift/Myplayground

Tags: swift, email, extract

I'm compartmentalizing users on firebase according to their email domain. What universal code can I use to extract only 'havard' in the following examples? All user emails end in '.edu'

let email = jsmith@student.havard.edu ,
let email = jsmith@havard.edu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple function that will work for the input set you provided.

```
func getMainPart(s: String) -> String {
    let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ".@")
    let v = s.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet)
    let pos = v.count - 2
    return v[pos]
}
```

Here's another solution:

```
func getMainPart2(s: String) -> String {
    var v = s.componentsSeparatedByString("@").last?.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    v?.removeLast()

    return (v!.last)!
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
let email1 = "smith@harvard.edu"
let s = getMainPart2(email1)
print(s) // this outputs: harvard
```

Answer (score 1):

One legal email address has only one "@" so separate email address:

```
public func componentsSeparatedByString(separator: String) -> [String]
```

This is sample code:

```
let components = email.componentsSeparatedByString("@").last?.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
if let index = components?.endIndex.advancedBy(-2) {
    components![index]
}
```

Comment: For "jsmith@student.havard.edu" this will output 'student' which is not what OP asked for.

Comment: @ryantxr I'm so so so sorry.But do you want to get 'havard' from email like this  jsmith@student.havard.edu.uk ?

Comment: @Lumialxk no, only jsmith@student.havard.edu and jsmith@havard.edu

Comment: BTW, I like your use of .last.

Comment: @KayambaMukanzu I'm sorry that I know little about firebase.